# How to create this variable in Latex?

Tags: latex

[image]

How do I create this in Latex? I tried `$r^e_{\_}$` or `$r^e\_$` but none give the variable as shown in the added picture.

Comment: Can you clarify which properties your first solution doesn't fulfil?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz hi sam, yeah I just noticed, the first solution I tried might be the answer, in my Latex editor it seems to look different from the image as shown here however. But after taking a closer look at the image,  $r^e_{\_}$ might be right answer, thanks.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz on the image I posted here it looked like the underscore was at the same height as the r but if you take a close look, then you see they are not. I guess $r^e_{\_}$ should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the underscore up a bit with

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$r^{e}_{\raisebox{0.21em}{\_}}$ 

\end{document}
```

[image]